# Having trouble passing text from MySQL to a Javascript function using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

So here's the problem.  I have data in a MySQL DB as text.  The data is inserted via mysql_real_escape_string.  I have no problem with the data being displayed to the user.

At some point I want to pass this data into a javascript function called foo.

```
// This is a PHP block of code
// $someText is text retrieved from the database

echo "<img src=someimage.gif onclick=\"foo('{$someText}')\">";
```

If the data in $someText has line breaks in it like:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

The javascript breaks because the html output is

```
<img src=someimage.gif onclick="foo('line1
line2
line3')">
```

So the question is, how can I pass $someText to my javascript foo function while preserving line breaks and carriage returns but not breaking the code?

===========================================================================================

After using json like this:

```
echo "<img src=someimage.gif onclick=\"foo($newData)\">";
```

It is outputting HTML like this:

```
onclick="foo("line 1<br \/>\r\nline 2");">
```

Which displays the image followed by \r\nline 2");">

Comment: One solution would be to use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). [More info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-including-escaping-newlines)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-including-escaping-newlines

Comment: do you want the values to be in a single line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json_encode()` is the way to go:

```
$json = json_encode($someText); # this creates valid JS
$safe = HtmlSpecialChars($json); # this allows it to be used in an HTML attribute
echo "<img src=someimage.gif onclick=\"foo($safe)\">";
```

You can see a demo here: http://codepad.org/TK45YErZ

Comment: I've updated the question after using json.  Any suggestions for the problem that is occurring?

Comment: Updated with the bit you're probably missing - quotes inside quotes need to be html escaped too.

Comment: That was what I needed Cal.  Thank you very much.  As soon as I have 15 reputation I will vote this up.  Thanks again!

Comment: One more question if you're still around.  Now that it has passed to my script, I'm having the data display in a textarea to the user, however I don't want the data to be shown with <br /> etc, is there a javascript equivalent to json_decode()?

Comment: it sounds like you're storing the '<br>' in your database, which is probably not what you want to be doing. you could solve it a few ways, but an easy hack would be to do `document.getElementById('my-textarea').innerHTML = the_data;` so that the browser decodes the HTML for you.

Comment: alternatively, you could fix this in PHP before generating the HTML, using `str_replace('<br />', "\n", $in);` - http://codepad.org/4BBc77B3

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not interpreting badly you may do this:

```
// This is a PHP block of code
// $someText is text retrieved from the database

echo "<img src=someimage.gif onclick=\"foo('{".trim( preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ',$someText ) )."}')\">";
```

Comment: This will remove any kind of new line and effectively alter `$someText`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll save yourself a lot of headaches by pulling the JavaScript out of the HTML:

```
<img id="myImage" src="someimage.gif"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var str = <?php echo json_encode($json); ?>;
    document.getElementById('myImage').addEventListener(
        'click',
        function() {
            foo(str);
        }
    );
</script>
```

Or something similer...

Answer (score 0):

Only json_encode() is enough to escape the new line

```
echo "<img src=someimage.gif onclick=\"foo(".json_encode($newData).")\">";
```